Undefined reference when trying to include headers in c++
guys, im trying to separate certain functions into another file with headers, but i ran into problem with undefined reference to `make_histogram(std::vector<double, std::allocator > const&, unsigned long&). histogram.h and histogram.cpp is located in one folder without any subfolders.
main.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "histogram.h"
using namespace std;

struct Input {
    vector<double> numbers;
    size_t bin_count{};
};

Input
input_data() {
    Input in;

    size_t number_count;
    cerr << "Enter quantity of numbers: ";
    cin >> number_count;

    vector<double> numbers(number_count);
    in.numbers.resize(number_count);
    cerr << "Enter numbers: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_count; i++) {
        cin >> in.numbers[i];
    }

    cerr << "Enter bin count: ";
    cin >> in.bin_count;

    return in;
}

int
main(){
    auto in = input_data();
    auto bins = make_histogram(in.numbers, in.bin_count);
    show_histogram_text(bins, in.bin_count);
}

histogram.h
#ifndef HISTOGRAM_H_INCLUDED
#define HISTOGRAM_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<size_t>
make_histogram(const vector<double>& numbers, size_t & bin_count);

void
find_minmax(const vector<double>& numbers, double& min, double& max);

void
show_histogram_text(vector<size_t>& bins, size_t& bin_count);

#endif // HISTOGRAM_H_INCLUDED


histogram.cpp
#include "histogram.h"

vector <size_t>
make_histogram(const vector<double>& numbers, size_t & bin_count) {
    double min, max;
    find_minmax(numbers, min, max);
    double bin_size = (max - min) / bin_count;
    vector<size_t> bins(bin_count);
    size_t max_count = bins[0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        bool found = false;
        for (size_t j = 0; (j < bin_count - 1) && !found; j++){
            auto lo = min + j * bin_size;
            auto hi = min + (j + 1) * bin_size;
            if ((lo <= numbers[i]) && (numbers[i] < hi)){
                bins[j]++;
                found = true;
            }
            if (bins[j] > max_count){
                max_count = bins[j];
            }
        }
        if (!found){
            bins[bin_count - 1]++;
        }
        if (bins[bin_count - 1] > max_count){
            max_count = bins[bin_count - 1];
        }
    }
    return bins;
}

void
find_minmax(const vector<double>& numbers, double& min, double& max) {
    if (!numbers.empty()) {
        min = numbers[0];
        max = numbers[0];
    } else {
        min = 0;
        max = 0;
    }
    for (double x : numbers)
    {
        if (x < min){
            min = x;
        }
        else if (x > max){
            max = x;
        }
    }
}

void show_histogram_text(const vector<size_t>& bins, size_t& bin_count) {
    const size_t SCREEN_WIDTH = 80;
    const size_t MAX_ASTERISK = SCREEN_WIDTH - 3 - 1;

    int max_count = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<bin_count;i++){
        if (bins[i]>max_count){
            max_count=bins[i];
        }
    }
    if (max_count>MAX_ASTERISK){
        for (int i=0; i<bin_count; i++){
            size_t height = MAX_ASTERISK * (static_cast<double>(bins[i]) / max_count);
            if (bins[i]<10){
                cout<<"  "<<bins[i]<<"|";
                for (int j=0;j<height;j++){
                    cout<<"*";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
            else if(bins[i]<100){
                cout<<" "<<bins[i]<<"|";
                for (int j=0;j<height;j++){
                    cout<<"*";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout<<bins[i]<<"|";
                for (int j=0;j<height;j++){
                    cout<<"*";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }

    }
    }else{
        for (int i=0; i<bin_count; i++){
            if (bins[i]<10){
                cout<<"  "<<bins[i]<<"|";
                for (int j=0;j<bins[i];j++){
                    cout<<"*";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
            else if(bins[i]<100){
                cout<<" "<<bins[i]<<"|";
                for (int j=0;j<bins[i];j++){
                    cout<<"*";
                }
            cout<<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout<<bins[i]<<"|";
                for (int j=0;j<bins[i];j++){
                    cout<<"*";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }

        }
    }
}

Where could the problem be? Help, please <3

You need to link everything together at the end, or, of you're building with a single command, then you need to list all the .cpp files in the same command.

Do not tag C for C++ questions.

The folder location almost always has nothing at all to do with the problem. Most IDEs and build systems will allow you to design your folder structure how you want. With that said you may be using VSCode which builds only the active file (official documentation tells you about this) by default and ignores all other source files. For that IDE once you have more than 1 file you have to do some manual work and give up using code-runner or switch to using Makefiles or CMake.

From the looks of it, histogram.cpp is simply not part of the project / not being linked.

Looks like one of those const std::vector ...  to std::vector ... const problems.  Try moving the const to the back of the std::vector

It's simple, make_histogram is in histogram.cpp therefore histogram.cpp is not being compiled. It seems to be a common beginner misunderstanding, including histogram.h does not magically make histogram.cpp get compiled, you have to do that as well as including histogram.h
